# PowerBI - How to create an approval process in PowerBI Dashboard?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am working on the reporting project that uses PowerBI as the data visualization tool.
I need create a processing approval workflow on the PowerBI tool. After seeing the Dashboard, the employer can approve some exception cases and the workflow can direct connect with email or ticket system.
There are 2 cases:

1. Approve for the whole dashboard that supports to be easy. I don't have any problem here.
2. Approve for singular object/row in a table chart. So I must generate number of buttons according to the number of row, which I need help. I don't know how to generate dynamic number of buttons and attached to row. And how to program/code it to create a view or action to become an approval step.

[Button PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWFZn.png)
In this screenshot, my plan is create buttons in each row and each button has the same function with parameter is username or IP. And after that I can send email to the user and notice him/her that his/her case is approve for exception.

I find this https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/A-simple-and-fun-guide-to-Microsoft-Flow-and-Power-BI/ba-p/151530. But it doesn't seem helpful. Anyone here has ever dealt with approval case like this.

Is PowerBI able to do the approval process like I want?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your not going to be able to do this in Power BI with the buttons, on row by row basis. In PBI Paginated Report you can, but you'll need Premium Per User licensees or Premium Capacity

Comment: Do you have another tool to deal with approval process except PowerBI? The approval process is more important than visualization in my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: This kind of goes against the spirit of BI in general. BI is for data visualization, exploration, etc. It's not really a UI for inserting data and executing tasks. Maybe you want instead to have a front end that lets you do things, and only needs to handle a very limited dataset? PowerApps is good for that. If the dataset is less than 1000 rows, this could work.

Second: I'm pretty sure it's not possible to create a button (like one that you'd see in an HTML page) that does what you want it to do in a Power BI table visual.

Third: There is a "drill through" button capability, but this just lets you navigate from one area in the report to another, not send an email or execute a Power Automate flow or anything like that. You may have seen a button on a table visual, but it's misleading. It's not really programmable like an HTML/JS button on a website.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-drill-through-button-in-power-bi/

That said, within the last 1.5 years or so, we now have the PowerApps add-in available. You could create an app that utilizes your streaming dataset, create a gallery that looks at that dataset and creates a kind of table with buttons on it, and then each button is set to execute the flow you've created in Power Automate.

[PowerApp Add in chiclet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJZWp.png)

All of this is very, extremely straightforward, but beware, the PowerApp will start to cost you extra money depending on where your data is housed. If it's a SQL server, you'll need both a premium PowerApp license and Power Automate license too.

Sorry for the not so great news, but this is kind of a limitation of Power BI.

Comment: Although I quitted that company, but I really appreciate your answer. I knew it was impossible task from beginning but the superior insisted. I really have no choice. After quitted, I really relieved, and now I don't need to deal with that kind of task anymore.